# Git URL - Pull out substring via Shell (awk & sed)?

Tags: awk, sed

I have got the following URL:

```
https://xcg5847@git.rz.bankenit.de/scm/smat/sma-mes-test.git
```

I need to pull out `smat-mes-test` and `smat`:

```
git config --local remote.origin.url|sed -n 's#.*/\([^.]*\)\.git#\1#p'
```

sma-mes-test

This works. But I also need the project name, which is `smat`

I am not really familiar to complex regex and sed, I was able to find the other command in another post here. Does anyone know how I am able to extract the `smat` value here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, setting field separator(s) as `/` and `.git` for all the lines and in main program printing 3rd last and 3nd last elements from the line.

```
your_git_command | awk -F'/|\\.git' '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: Thank you, all solutions are great, but your´s is the only I completely understand ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `sed` is pretty close. You can just extend it to capture 2 values and print them:

```bash
git config --local remote.origin.url |
sed -E 's~.*/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.git$~\1 \2~'

smat sma-mes-test
```

If you want to populate shell variable using these 2 values then use this `read` command in `bash`:

```bash
read v1 v2 < <(git config --local remote.origin.url |
sed -E 's~.*/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.git$~\1 \2~')

# check variable values
declare -p v1 v2
declare -- v1="smat"
declare -- v2="sma-mes-test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's#.*/([^/]*)/#\1 #' input_file
smat sma-mes-test.git
```

Comment: I think OP needs `sma-mes-test` instead of `sma-mes-test.git`

Comment: @anubhava Good catch. I think you are right reading the question again. In which case, your answer is clearly better than mine. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
https://xcg5847@git.rz.bankenit.de/scm/smat/sma-mes-test.git
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{sub(/\.git$/,"",$NF);print $(NF-1),$NF}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
smat sma-mes-test
```

Explanation: I instruct GNU `AWK` that field separator is slash character, then I replace `.git` (observe that `.` is escaped to mean literal dot) adjacent to end (`$`) in last field (`$NF`), then I print 2nd from end field (`$(NF-1)`) and last field (`$NF`), which are sheared by space, which is default output field separator, if you wish to use other character for that purpose set `OFS` (output field separator) in `BEGIN`. If you want to know more about `NF` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

(tested in gawk 4.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Why not `sed 's!.*/\(.*/.*\)!\1!'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
string=$(config --local remote.origin.url | tail -c -21)

var1=$(echo "${string}" | cut -d'/' -f1)
var2=$(echo "${string}" | cut -d'/' -f2 | sed s'@\.git@@')
```

If you have multiple urls with variable lengths, this will not work, but if you only have the one, it will.

```
var1=smat
var2=sma-mes-test.git
```

If I did have something variable, personally I would replace all of the forward slashes with carriage returns, throw them into a file, and then export the last and second last lines with ed, which would give me the two last segments of the url.

Regular expressions literally give me a migraine headache, but as long as I can get everything on its' own line, I can quite easily bypass the need for them entirely.